# Php files downloading instead of opening using Parse.com

Tags: php, parse-platform

I uploaded the files to the public directory.

This is what I have in the index file:

```
<?php
require_once( 'autoload.php' );
echo "Hello there";
?>
```

And here is the link to that file: 
http://mens.parseapp.com/php/index.php

I included the SDK: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk

I'm a bit confuse about what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: He lies, this isn't what is in the file.

Comment: :s I forgot to edit the file. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: How can I install PHP on Parse.com I don't see any information on how to do this on their website :/

Comment: have you read this? https://www.parse.com/docs/php/guide

Comment: Yes, I have. Many times :/ and I still don't know how to do this. They say that you don't need to use composer if you don't want to: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk#alternative-method I already uploaded the SDK and linked the required file :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<?  <--
require_once( 'autoload.php' );

echo "Hello stupid fuckers";

require 'GCMPushMessage.php';

...
```

It's something wrong with your server configuration. I would give a try to use

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't install php on your server, or if you have, try reinstalling it.

Comment: How can I install PHP on Parse.com I don't see any information on how to do this on their website :/

Comment: Try changing the extention to .html and let me know if that works @RaulGarcia

Comment: That sounds stupid but I just thought it might work since parse doesn't support php, here is the reference: https://www.parse.com/questions/parse-hosting-supports-html-file-with-embedded-php-code @RaulGarcia